# .htaccess Url Rewrite and Redirect

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am trying to redirect a website from one domain to another and rewrite the url. This is what I have come up with in the .htaccess. It is redirecting but not rewriting the url. What am I doing wrong?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain1.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://20038770.domain2.com [P]
```

Comment: @anubhava I just tried without the www version and it still redirects with no rewrite.

Comment: That means `mod_proxy` is not correctly setup.

Comment: @anubhava Is that on the domain1 server or the domain2 server?

Comment: `mod_proxy` should be setup in Apache config of `domain1`

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to add `[OR]` to first RewriteCond to make rule work for *both* domain1.com and www.domain1.com. Without `[OR]` mod_rewrite uses for two conditions `[AND]` by default (and the host name can't be domain1.com *and* www.domain1.com in the same request).
2. You forgot $1 in `RewriteRule` which is needed for copying local path matched by (.*) from old URL to new.

The correct .htaccess will be:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.com$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain1.com$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) http://20038770.domain2.com/$1 [P]
```